# Question about notation $\int_{0}^tf(r)dr$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, notation

I see this notation a lot but I am not sure why we write  $\int_{0}^tf(r)dr$  instead of $\int_0^tf(t)dt$. If we assume $\int f(x)dx=F(x)$ we have:

$$\int_0^t f(r)dr=F(r)|_{r=0}^{r=t}=F(t)-F(0)$$
$$\int_0^t f(t)dt=F(t)|_{t=0}^{t=t}=F(t)-F(0)$$

And we get $F(t)-F(0)$ in both case.I saw this notation in such integrals a lot but  I don't understand the logic of presenting a new variable (which is "$r$" here) to calculate the definite integral. And is it logically (or mathematically) wrong to write $\int_0^tf(t)dt$ instead of $\int_0^tf(r)dr$?

Comment: Yes, $\int_0^{t}f(t)dt$ does not make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't know the reason. It seems $\int_0^{t}f(t)dt$ means the area under the curve $f(t)$ where $t\in (0,t)$. and it seems logical to me. So I don't completely understand why it doesn't make sence.

Comment: You are using the same variable twice as a variable in $f(t)$, and as a number in the bounds of integration from $0$ to $t$. $t$ cannot be a variable and a number at the same time.